# How can I dynamically upsert data in object

Tags: apex, dml, httprequest, loop, upsert

I want to upsert data in SF based on the selected columns by the user. I make HTTP callout to an external service and it returns the data. Then, I want to iterate over the each returned row and create custom object instance.

The data returned is as follows **(!Dummy Data)**:

[image: Dummy data]

As you can see, the user has selected 4 columns and for each returned row, there is a list of 4 values (null counts as value).

Now, I want to iterate each of this rows and create record in SF.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
if (res.getStatusCode() == 200){ 
    Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                    
    // DML
    List<Object> resultsData = (List<Object>) results.get('data');
                 
    List<Custom_Object__c> upsertRecord= new List<Custom_Object__c>();
    for (Object dataIte : resultsData) {
        Custom_Object__c cc = new Custom_Object__c();
        for(String column : sessionMustHaveColumns){
            cc.column = 
        }
        upsertRecord.add(cc);
        System.debug(dataIte);
    }
    upsert upsertRecord;
    return res.getBody();
}
```

The list **sessionMustHaveColumns** contains API names of the fields on the object that the data needs to be upserted. But when I want to dynamically assign cc.column = |value| it gives me error - that field doesn't exist, which is logical.

How can I assign value to a dynamical column per object and iterate over all this data?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1 9/11/2022:**

How can I iterate over each element of the row which is object type??

**EDIT 2 10/11/2022**

```
15:07:50:107 USER_DEBUG [141]|DEBUG|((15250809629146723, 5957676d3b753f69, 2021-02-18T07:19:04, , 5957676d3b753f69), (20487780899778413, 7a5911e7f5731400, 2021-01-26T15:54:48, , 7a5911e7f5731400), (27450806533608027, 186af40e19b1cfdf, 2021-02-27T00:55:45, ruari.sparks752@pmail.com, 186af40e19b1cfdf), (41195804276029081, 2ec0802a5c592800, 2021-01-22T06:33:13, , 2ec0802a5c592800), (41346057691525410, 67e89542fb518400, 2021-02-06T07:47:28, , 67e89542fb518400), (64024758225093621, 201f2c0d93952a00, 2021-02-25T07:36:12, ,), (64024752225093621, 201g2c0d93952a00, 2021-02-26T07:36:12, ,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(Object row : allData){
  List<Object> dataList = (List<Object>) row;
  for (String rowMapKey : listOfFields){
 *code here*}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To assign value dynamically you can use `put(fieldName, value)`.

```java
for (String column : sessionMustHaveColumns){
   cc.put(column, 'some value here'); 
}
```

Of course, `column` must exist as a custom/standard field on the `Custom_Object__c`.

Resources:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put

Comment: that seems to work fine. One side question - how can I iterate each element of the row? For example, first row first element. Because it's object I don't really understand it.

Comment: Change `List<Object> resultsData = (List<Object>) results.get('data');` to `List<List<Object>> resultsData = (List<List<Object>>) results.get('data');` and use `for (List<Object> row : resultsData)` and add inner loop `for (Object item : row)`. item will be concrete value.

Comment: I get `Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to List<List<ANY>>`  on a line `List<Object> resultsData = (List<Object>) results.get('data');`

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give me the output from System.debug(result.get('data'));

Comment: I've edited my question and added  System.debug(result.get('data')); response - EDIT 2.